# Why is Android Studio not Recognizing Third Party Dependencies?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Whenever I install Gradle third-party dependencies, my android studio project doesn't recognize the library classes. For example, I've tried installing a library called **fuzzydateformatter**. Android studio doesn't recognize the classes from that library. I've also tried installing other third-party libraries but the same thing happens. Only google and androidx libraries seem to work fine.

```
// Time Formatter
implementation 'si.virag:fuzzydateformatter:1.1.0'
```

**PS:** I'm new to android and I use kotlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[That library](https://github.com/izacus/FuzzyDateFormatter) has not been updated in six years. It is only published on JCenter, which has threatened shutdown a few times. As a result, JCenter is not included as a repository in modern Android Studio projects.

The best solution would be to use another library, one that is actively being maintained.

If you insist on using this library, your choices are:

- Use the source code of the library directly, copying it out of GitHub into your project, or
- Adding `jcenter()` as a repository, in the same spot(s) in your project where you have `google()` and `mavenCentral()` (e.g., `repositories` closures in your project-level `build.gradle` file)